# How to tackle this compound interest homework?

Tags: java

I have been given an assignment:

> Write a recursive method that given an initial amount of investment ($) and the interest rate and the number of years, it calculates the amount at the end of n years. Note that the interest is compounded annually.
>
> Use the following method signature
>
> ```
> public static double invest(double amount, double rate, int year)
> ```
>
> where
>
> - amount is the investment amount
> - rate is the annual interest rate
> - year is the number of years of investment
>
> For instance
>
> - invest(2000, 0.07, 1) returns 2140
> - invest(5000, 0.05, 10) returns 8144.47313 (some digits are omitted for brevity)
>
> Then write a program to test your method.

This is my programs

```
public class Investment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(invest(2000, 0.07, 1));

    }

    public static double invest(double amount, double rate, int year) {
        if (amount == 0 || rate == 0 || year == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return amount * (1 + (rate * year));
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, I do not know if it is recursive method or not and if not. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: sure is not recursive - a recursive method must call itself. E.g. sum of all numbers from 1 to n (or from n to 1) : `public int sum(int n) { if (n > 1) return n + sum(n-1); else return n; }`

Comment: Recursive means the method calls itself - i.e. `invest` must call `invest` somewhere in it.

Comment: `if (year <= 0) { return amount; } else { return invest(amount * (1 + rate), rate, year - 1); }`

Comment: Thank you for your help, still not know how to do it though, I mean I do not know how to write the compound interest formula in recursive form. Can you explain for me, please?

Comment: (Pro tip: if you wish for your comments to be seen by people you reply to, always use an `@` sign followed immediately with their name, with no spaces. If you type the first letter or two, you can `Tab` auto-complete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, a recursive method is, put simply, a method that calls itself. For example, a recursive method that calculates the factorial of a given positive integer `n` could be as follows:

```
public int factorial(int n) {
    if(n == 1 || n == 0) return 1;
    return factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
```

So for example, `factorial(3)` would yield 6. Breaking it down, the return value of the "first call" would be `factorial(2) * 3`, which is exactly what the factorial of 3 is. However, the same method could be written in a non-recursive way, like:

```
public int factorial(int n) {
   int result = 1;
   while(n > 0) {
       result *= n;
   }
   return result;
}
```

This takes more than a little bit of practice and understanding, but you can write every recursive method as an iterative one, and vice-versa. The trick for doing the latter is trying to isolate the logic "inside" the cycle, and then using recursive calls as a way of "advancing" the iteration. I'd advise you to first design an iterative method,  like:

```
public static double invest(double amount, double rate, int year) {
    //while year is not 0
       //apply rate over calculated amount
    //return calculated amount
}
```

And from there, try to extrapolate it into recursive logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Investment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(invest(2000, 0.07, 1));
    }

    public static double invest(double amount, double rate, int year) {
        if(year > 0){
          double newAmount = amount + (amount * rate);
          return invest(newAmount, rate, year--);
        }
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Recursive method is just that you call the method that you are inside, you can see that i call `invest` inside `invest`, but i stop doing that when `year` reached `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Compound_Interest
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        double amt=calc(100.00, 0.10, 3);
        System.out.println(amt);
    }
    public static double calc(double p, double r, double t)
    {
        //p is principal, r=rate, t=time
        if (p>0)
        {
            if (t>0)
            {       
                p=p*r+p;
                return (calc(p,r,t-1));
            }
            }
        return p;
    }
}
```

II used the formula for simple interest to calculate compound interest. Simple interest formula is:

SI = P*R*T.

The accumulation of all the simple interests (P*R*T) is added to the original principle to get the new value of the bank account.

The call statements are added from the bottom up. This follows the principle of Last In first Out (LIFO) which forms the basis for recursion.

Hope this helps!